# How do I get a multi-node Keycloak cluster running with docker containers (no k8/swarm/etc)?

Tags: keycloak

I have three EC2 instances in AWS:

- instance A - docker with nginx container - private IP address 1.2.3.4
- instance B and C - docker with keycloak containers - private IP address 1.2.3.5 and 1.2.3.6
- RDS instance running MySQL 8 - host foo.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com

All in the same VPC. Instance B and C are in different subnets (different availability zones), but can communicate with each other via port 80 and 7600.

The docker instances launch without issue with the following command:

```
  docker run \
  --name test-node-1 \
  -e DB_PORT=3306 \
  -e PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true \
  -e DB_VENDOR=mysql \
  -e DB_DATABASE=keycloak \
  -e DB_ADDR=foo.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com \
  -e KEYCLOAK_STATISTICS=all \
  -e DB_USER=keycloak \
  -e KEYCLOAK_USER=kcuser \
  -e DB_PASSWORD=... \
  -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=... \
  -p 80:8080 \
  -p 7600:7600 \
  jboss/keycloak:16.1.0
```

Both containers launch fine, but they aren't talking to each other.

Adding the following three environment variables:

```
  -e JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_EXTERNAL_IP=1.2.3.5 \
  -e JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROTOCOL=TCPPING \
  -e JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROPERTIES='1.2.3.5[7600],1.2.3.6[7600]' \
```

Causes Keycloak to crash on startup:

```
=========================================================================

  Using MySQL database

=========================================================================

17:01:35,028 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (CLI command executor) JBoss Modules version 2.0.0.Final
17:01:35,124 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (CLI command executor) JBoss MSC version 1.4.13.Final
17:01:35,134 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (CLI command executor) JBoss Threads version 2.4.0.Final
17:01:35,267 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: Keycloak 16.1.0 (WildFly Core 18.0.0.Final) starting
...
17:01:43,320 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
17:01:43,322 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: Keycloak 16.1.0 (WildFly Core 18.0.0.Final) started in 3261ms - Started 49 of 79 services (31 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
The batch executed successfully
17:01:43,560 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0050: Keycloak 16.1.0 (WildFly Core 18.0.0.Final) stopped in 21ms
Setting JGroups discovery to TCPPING with properties {1.2.3.5[7600],1.2.3.6[7600]}
```

That last log line hangs for a few seconds, and then the process crashes.  Note that it's the **FIRST** instance that crashes (I never get to launching the second one), so I don't think it's a matter of communication/firewall/etc, but port 80 and 7600 are open.

I'm using the [jboss/Keycloak docker image v16.1 from Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/layers/jboss/keycloak/16.1.0/images/sha256-6ecb9492224c6cfbb55d43f64a5ab634145d8cc1eba14eae8c37e3afde89546e?context=explore).

Comment: It doesn' make sense to have `-e JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_EXTERNAL_IP=1.2.3.5 \` on host A (which has IP 1.2.3.4). Also https://www.keycloak.org/2019/05/keycloak-cluster-setup refers to different syntax for JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROPERTIES

Comment: Instance A (IP 1.2.3.4) is only an nginx server, so there is no JGROUPS settings at all.  Instance B (IP 1.2.3.5) is the first Keycloak server, which has JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_EXTERNAL_IP set to it's own IP address.

Comment: I have read through keycloak.org/2019/05/keycloak-cluster-setup (although it has a warning that it may be out of date).  I believe what I have posted is inline with those suggestions (namely `JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_EXTERNAL_IP`, `JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROTOCOL`, and `JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROPERTIES` settings), but the server crashes when they are added.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container will need a TCPPING.cli script, or the appropriate modifications made to standalone-ha.xml.  The following TCPPING.cli file worked for me (mounted into the docker container with `-v $(pwd)/TCPPING.cli:/opt/jboss/tools/cli/jgroups/discovery/TCPPING.cli`):

```
embed-server --server-config=standalone-ha.xml --std-out=echo
batch

/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=keycloak/distributed-cache=sessions:write-attribute(name=owners, value=${env.CACHE_OWNERS:2})
/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=keycloak/distributed-cache=authenticationSessions:write-attribute(name=owners, value=${env.CACHE_OWNERS:2})
/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=keycloak/distributed-cache=offlineSessions:write-attribute(name=owners, value=${env.CACHE_OWNERS:2})
/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=keycloak/distributed-cache=loginFailures:write-attribute(name=owners, value=${env.CACHE_OWNERS:2})

/subsystem=jgroups/stack=udp:remove()

/subsystem=jgroups/stack=tcp/protocol=MPING:remove()
/subsystem=jgroups/stack=tcp/protocol=$keycloak_jgroups_discovery_protocol:add(add-index=0, properties={"initial_hosts"=>$keycloak_jgroups_discovery_protocol_properties})

/subsystem=jgroups/channel=ee:write-attribute(name=stack, value="tcp")

/subsystem=jgroups/stack=tcp/transport=TCP/property=external_addr/:add(value=${env.JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_EXTERNAL_IP:127.0.0.1})

run-batch
stop-embedded-server
```

Note that this is different from what is recommended in https://www.keycloak.org/2019/05/keycloak-cluster-setup - specifically the line

```
/subsystem=jgroups/stack=tcp/protocol=$keycloak_jgroups_discovery_protocol:add(add-index=0, properties={"initial_hosts"=>$keycloak_jgroups_discovery_protocol_properties})
```

I also changed the `JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROPERTIES` env var to only be the first server (e.g. `-e JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROPERTIES=1.2.3.5[7600]`) - each server in the cluster should just need to check with the master in order to join.